# No homescreen button in B2G emulator

Tags: firefox-os, gaia

I build the code for b2g and gaia via downloading the latest from mozilla repo.

Once the build is done.. when I launched there is not home button visible. Please help me regarding this...

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox OS Simulator[1] is a Firefox plugin which launches B2G Desktop and provides a simulated home button, B2G Desktop builds alone do not have this. But you can just use the home button on your keyboard!

1. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/

Answer (score 1):

In B2G desktop you can emulate home button with FN+LEFT (OSX) or HOME (Windows).